# How often can I reinflate my tire

Tags: motorcycle, tires

How often should I reinflate my tire. My bike has tubeless back tire and tubed front tire. Currently I am reinflating once in a week with 35psi(back) and 25 psi(front).

Should I need to reinflate my front tire everytime when I reinflate back tire ?

Comment: I think you should clarify how old your tire is as well. Check to see if there is a 4-digit code stamped on each tire.

Comment: What type of bike is it? 25psi at the front sounds low to me, the ones I've had have always suggested the front be at least the same (if not higher pressure) than the rear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Background

There is no air pressure relationship between the front and rear tire.

## Possibility

It may sound coincidence but it appears you have two tires that are leaking.

To troubleshoot the issue, fill the tires to 40+ psi.  Have a bucket with soapy water and a rag or sponge handy and cover the surface area of the tires with the soapy water.  You will see bubbles in the areas where there are leaks and you can then patch/plug as necessary.  Be sure to check the shrader valve for bubbles where it emerges from the rim and for good measure take the valve cap off to see if there is actual leaking from the valve.

Good luck

Comment: Every time I fill the back tire the machine will start from 18psi is it the amount of air left in the tire ??

Answer (score 5):

You should fill your tires ***as often as they need filled***. Checking your tires once a week is a good maintenance schedule. If, while doing your checks, you discover one or both are low, add some air to them. If you discover there is a continual loss of pressure, you'll need to get the tires checked for leaks as @DukatiKiller suggests. There is no reason to check just one tire and not the other tire, but as was also stated, there is no correlation between the two tires. Do what you need to do to keep them at the proper pressure for the best ride experience, for piece of mind, and for safety's sake.

Answer (score 4):

No one has mentioned that the schrader valve could be leaking air too.  Older valves may have their rubber seals deteriorate over time and leak.

When you do the soapy water test, you might want to try putting some over the schrader valve area as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should check tire pressure every single time you leave home, along with chain tension. If your tires are leaking this much, you should have them replaced. In the meantime, fill them up every time you leave the house. Pro tip: a bicycle pump will work to fill your motorcycle tires, believe it or not. Keep one in the garage so you don't have to stop at a machine.

Comment: I use a bicycle pump for my car tires, too.  For my Outback it's 9 strokes per PSI, for my Sonic it's 6 strokes.